# What is the latest iOS 8.3 baseband for iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I want to update my iPhone 6 to iOS 8.3, but my device is unlocked with R-Sim. I want to know if the new iOS firmware will update the baseband & relock my device. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

2.23.03 for a european (Austria) GSM
Perhaps contact the vendor if it's compatible.